# Kotlin Android app failing to launch E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Here is the sample code of the Kotlin app:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    val inputbox0 : EditText = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.inputbox)
    val inputbox1 : EditText = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.inputbox2)
    val inputbox2 : EditText = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.inputbox3)
    val inputbox3 : EditText = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.inputbox4)

    var iboxstring0 = inputbox0.toString().toInt()
    var iboxstring1 = inputbox1.toString().toInt()
    var iboxstring2 = inputbox2.toString().toInt()
    var iboxstring3 = inputbox3.toString().toInt()

    var users = 0
    var ecpm = 0
    var minutes = 0
    var adsShown = 0
    var dailyincome = 0
    var dailyincomestr = dailyincome.toString()
    fun calc(){
        dailyincome = users/1000*ecpm* minutes*adsShown
    }
    val button: Button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.calcbut)
    val textView : TextView = findViewById(R.id.displayview)
    button.setOnClickListener(){
        users = iboxstring0
        ecpm = iboxstring1
        minutes = iboxstring2
        adsShown = iboxstring3
        textView.setText("")
        calc()
        textView.append(dailyincomestr)

      }
   }
}
```

Here are the errors I am getting:

> 2020-02-22 21:33:49.531 10157-10157/com.example.admobincomecalculator
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.admobincomecalculator, PID: 10157
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.admobincomecalculator/com.example.admobincomecalculator.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "
>   androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText{c91444c VFED..CL. ......I.
>   0,0-0,0 #7f07004a app:id/inputbox}"
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3260)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3396)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2009)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7319)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:934)
>        Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText{c91444c VFED..CL.
>   ......I. 0,0-0,0 #7f07004a app:id/inputbox}"
>           at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
>           at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:650)
>           at com.example.admobincomecalculator.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:21)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7783)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7772)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1299)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3235)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3396) 
>           at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83) 
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2009) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7319) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:934)

[The error in android studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YeVeN.png)

Please help me to Solve these error.

Comment: what is on line 21 in the MainActivity onCreate method?

Comment: line 21 is: var iboxstring0 = inputbox0.toString().toInt()

Comment: the string in inputbox0 is "" according to the log, and when it tries to convert it to int it fails

surround the conversion with a try catch and provide a default value, it will stop crashing.

You would need to do this for all your string.toInt conversions

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60356951/how-can-you-close-a-question-without-reading-it